# Angularjs application fails to load UI properly on a chrome 76 launched by chromedriver 75 and above

Tags: angularjs, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

Open Angularjs application on chrome with chromedriver through selenium. Try to click on the buttons it moves constantly up and down, which makes it impossible to click and selenium fails to click as the application is bouncing on the screen.
However, tried to replicate the same with a chrome browser manually launched it never happens. 
Open the browser through chrome driver and launch the angularjs application manually UI keeps bouncing.
This means the issue happens only with a browser launched by chrome driver.

Tried with older chromedriver and chrome, this doesn't happen. Happens only with later releases of chromedriver i.e. 76 and above.
Angularjs version 1.7.2
Local chrome does work properly.

I used basic way of initiating the chrome with the below code, still no luck

```cs
var driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

Since the chrome browser behave differently only when launched through chromedriver, also since launching local chrome doesn't have an issue. I tried to launch the chrome as it would launch manually.

```cs
var options = new ChromeOptions() { AcceptInsecureCertificates = true };
            options.AddArguments($"user-data-dir=/Users/{Environment.UserName}/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data");
            var driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

The approach of using local profile user data does help to a certain extent when running on local machines, but when running on a remote machine it fails again and also you can't launch two browsers as the user data folder is used by one browser at a time, not feasible to have only one chrome browser and not multi threadable.

The latest chromedriver version 76 is w3c complaint so its better to use later versions than using older chromedriver.

Any suggestions or insights on why this happens only with chrome launched by chromedriver. will be well appreciated and also happens only with angular application.

Comment: W3C compliant != "always better".  Testing is for the real world and standards are not always obeyed by the browsers or the webdrivers.  Good news is v75 chromedriver does work with Chrome v76.

Comment: Agreed, 75 chromedriver works with chrome 76, however, the issue occur there also.